# How to get live transactions through websockets?

Tags: transactions, rpc, jsonrpc-api, api, websocket

Is there any method I can subscribe to in order to get live transactions data through websockets? I tried with `logsSubscribe` but it doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Did you find the answer? Please comment if yes

Answer (score 2):

See: https://docs.solana.com/api/websocket

You can subscribe to various accounts and information depending on what your desired outcome is. AccountSubscribe (https://docs.solana.com/api/websocket#accountsubscribe) is a likely candidate if you're looking for account changes otherwise ProgramSubscribe (https://docs.solana.com/api/websocket#programsubscribe) is good if you're looking for program interactions (eg swaps with a pool etc.).

Given you're looking for all token interactions, you need to make sure the RPC you're using has the methods available and are indexing the data with `--account-index` https://docs.solana.com/validator/get-started/setup-an-rpc-node#account-indexing. If you do not have these enabled, you will not get any data in the response.

You didn't ask, but excluding certain indexes ensures you keep performance from the RPC, so you may want to use `--account-index-exclude-key` for unrelated data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I would like to get all the SOL and Solana tokens transfers